# Serverless packaging issue

Tags: serverless-framework

I am using NodeJS 10 to create number of lambdas. Many functions has shared code that included into each function, so overall structure looks like:

```
project/
  function1/
    api.js
    serverless.yml    
  function2/
    api.js
    serverless.yml    
  function3/
    api.js
    serverless.yml    
  shared/
    http/
      index.js
      node_modules/
    intercom/
      index.js
      node_modules/
```

Each `serverless.yml` contains function declaration like:

```
functions:
  test-database-connection:
    package:
      include:
        - ../shared/http/**
        - ../shared/intercom/**
        - ./node_modules/**
        - ./api.js
    handler: api.connectivityDatabase
    events:
      - http:
          path: /api/test/database
          method: post
```

During development it works, also working offline well, but after packaging it becomes unusable because package changes relative paths to `shared` folder like:

```
package.zip/
  shared/
    http/
      ...
    intercom/
      ...
  api.js
```

Is it possible to keep same structure in package as during development? Or any other way to fix module paths that will work locally and on AWS both?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using npm, I recommend creating a `package.json` file in `shared`

Then you can simply require it in the `package.json` files in `function1` with a relative path:

```
  "name": "function1",
  "dependencies": {
    "shared": "file:../shared",
    ...
  }
```

Then you can remove the `package` logic from the `serverless.yml` file, and just let the package manager handle things. The Serverless Framework will resolve those packages when packaging your application for deployment.